# Compress recorded video in android cameraX

Tags: android, kotlin, android-camerax

I implemented video recording in the android cameraX library and I want to compress recorded video but I don't know how. how can I do that?

Comment: AFAIK, all video formats supported by CameraX are already compressed. You might want to explain in greater detail what you are looking to do.

Comment: @CommonsWare I think the videos are not compressed. I recorded 30 seconds video and I saw the recorded video is 75 mb. Is there special config to this?

Comment: Compression has [a very specific meaning in computer programming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_compression), and every [video format supported by Android](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/media-formats?hl=en#video-formats) is a compressed format. "Is there special config to this?" -- you are welcome to play with things like resolution and frame rate to try to get a smaller initial file. You are also welcome to transcode the initial file using things like `ffmpeg` to try to further reduce the file size.